# How to reorder list elements in unordered list using keyboard events ( Space + Down Arrow )?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wai-aria

I am trying to reorder list items using space+↓ to change the order in list in JavaScript. Please see code below:

```
 <ul id="ulist">
  <li tabindex="0">item one </li>
  <li tabindex="0">item two </li>
  <li tabindex="0">item three </li>
  <li tabindex="0">item four </li> 
</ul>
```

I am able to get through ( CTRL + Down Arrow)

```
    $('li').keydown(function(e) {
  var li= $(this);
  if(e.ctrlKey) {
    switch(e.which) {
      case 38: li.insertBefore(li.prev()); break; //up
      case 40: li.insertAfter(li.next());  break; //down
    }
    li.focus();
  }
});

$('li').first().focus();
```

How to do this ?

Comment: Have you tried anything in JS yet?

Comment: I don't see any code, only HTML markup. What about posting your own attempt, if any...

Comment: I have achieved using CTRL + Down arrow. But i need using SpaceBar + Down Arrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tricky, because the <kbd>Space bar</kbd> does not put the keyboard into a special state like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, or <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

You can do it by listening for the <kbd>Space bar</kbd>, and then changing the key events to listen for the up and down arrows:

```
$('li').keyup(function(e) {
  if(e.which===32) $(this).unbind('keydown');
  $(this).keydown(function(e) {
    var li= $(this);
    if(e.which===32) {
      li.unbind('keydown');
      li.keydown(function(e) {
        switch(e.which) {
          case 38: li.insertBefore(li.prev()); break; //up
          case 40: li.insertAfter(li.next());  break; //down
        }
        li.focus();
      });
    }
  });
}).keyup();
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/53mkwsbg/)

Comment: Good Job Rick. Thank You

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible. The control key is treated differently than the other keys. When you press a key while holding the ctrl key the ***ctrl key pressed*** event is triggered along with each subsequent press. (***This can be demonstrated by registering an event that prints to the console when the control key is pressed and one that prints to the console when any key pressed***). Whereas space key is treated as an ordinary key. The space key pressed event is fired once when you press it and any subsequent key presses while holding it will simply ignore it and fire keypress events for the latter key.

Comment: It has been implemented in Accessible Drag and Drop Functionality using Keyboard. I expect to do without using any plugin.

Comment: Space+↓ and [Space and then ↓] are not the same. I thought you are trying to press the two simultaneously. Now I think you meant something similar to http://whatsock.com/modules/aria_sortable_listbox_module/demo.htm

Comment: I am asking for reordering list not to sort.